# Where is the cmdline.txt on Windows IOT Dashboard installation?

Tags: windows-iot, cmdline.txt

I can't find the cmdline.txt file for my device.

I used the Windows IOT Dashboard to install the image on the SD-card of my Raspberry Pi 3

I want to switch GPIO14 (pin 08) and GPIO15 (pin 10) to GPIO usage.

Therefor I must delete the references to /dev/ttyAMA0 and /etc/inittab out of the cmdline.txt file.

But I can't find it, neither when I plugin the sd-card in my laptop, nor when I try it with powershell...

Can anybody tell me how to access that file?

Thanks in advance,
Heenne

EDIT: Clarified pin and GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure these files are relevant?  The instructions you are following are for a Linux based Raspberry Pi (/dev/ttyAMA0 and /etc/inittab are both Linux device/file names).

I wouldn't have thought these files would be present on a Windows IoT system.

Comment: I can't find any other information how to disable the uart on iot core, so I can use the two GPIOs for my GPIO-purpose

Comment: Aren't they used by WIndows IoT?  I'm sure this topic has been discussed on the official Windows IoT forum.  That is probably the best place to look for current information.

Comment: Because they are unused :D All the GPIO are free (vanilla image) to do what ever you tell it to do. There is no cmdline.txt either.

Comment: Currently I am developing my app in C# and I can open every pin with `defaultControler.OpenPin(pinNumber)` except the GPIOs 14 and 15. Just noticed, I mean GPIO14 and GPIO15, should be pin 08 & 10. 

Will edit that in my question

Comment: I have a memory of the UART being dedicated for debugging purposes in Windows IoT.  I saw discussion about this when it was launched on the Raspberry Pi.  I thought there was a workaround but I don't use IoT and haven't looked at the IoT forums for months.